# Join 2 searches on Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, spl

I have a table that refers to our threat intelligence IoC, and a table that refers to the company user logins.

I want to find the logins that come from an Ip address contained in our IoC list.

i tried with

```
"o365_management_activity" AND Operation=UserLoggedIn
| table user, src_ip 
| rename src_ip AS event.indicator 
| join event.indicator  [search (index="threatstream_summary") (sourcetype="stash") 
  | table event.indicator]
```

but i cannot find any result (even if i remove "AND Operation=UserLoggedIn").

What am i missing?

thank you for helping

i tried a lot of query and read a lot, but no results

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is missing is an index name in the base search.  Without it, Splunk will only read your default indexes (if you have any defined), which may not contain the data you seek.

Try to avoid the `join` command since it does not perform well.  Try `append`, instead.  How Splunk interprets field names with dots can be problematic so consider using src_ip instead of event.indicator.

```
index=foo "o365_management_activity" AND Operation=UserLoggedIn
| fields user, src_ip 
| append [search index=threatstream_summary sourcetype=stash
  | rename "event.indicator" as src_ip 
  | table src_ip ]
| stats values(*) as * by src_ip
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. 

Your query does not work, anyway.

I tried to use append in the following query:
((index="o365_security") (sourcetype="o365:management:activity")) 
| table user, src_ip 
| append [search index=threatstream_summary sourcetype=stash | rename event.indicator AS indicator | table indicator ]

now i have 3 columns: user, src_ip and indicator. But the column "Indicator" has blank values untile the "src_ip rows are filled.

Comment: Both searches have to have a shared field.  In my query, that field is src_ip.  Please elaborate on "your query does not work".